# how to center my google map script with divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so far the text is centered the google maps page hugs the left and then the text underneath it remains centered, i just want the map to be centered.

```
<div id="row1">
    <div id="note"><img src="http://www.bristol.gov.uk/sites/default/files/styles/hero_image/public/images/children_and_young_people/resources_for_professionals/head_teachers_and_school_administrators/hr/contact_us/we%20will%20be%20back%20soon-sticky%20note.jpg?itok=08vLR_lO"></div>
    <div id = "hours">
        Sorry<br>
        hours<br>
    </div>
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px; width:600px;"></div>
    Below text
</div>
```

Style:

```
#row1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Google Map JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.0820037, -14.26733380000002),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(20.0820037, -14.26733380000002)
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<b>Crokson Dine In</b><br/>43 Gill Rd<br/>09521 Hovill"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

Comment: `#gmap_canvas { margin: 0 auto;}` may do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align: center` cannot center a block element itself. You need auto margins:

```
<div
    id="gmap_canvas"
    style="height:500px; width:600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```